# How to invert an RGB color in integer form?

Tags: graphics, colors

Given an RGB color in 32-bit unsigned integer form (eg. 0xFF00FF), how would you invert it (get a negative color), without extracting its individual components using bitshift operations?

I wonder whether it's possible using just bitwise operations (AND, OR, XOR).

More precisely, what's the algorithm that uses the least number of instructions?

Comment: 0xFF00FF is only 3 bytes or 24bits, NOT 32bits.

Comment: I'm interested only in colors so the remaining byte is irrelevant and hence omitted. Thanks for downvoting.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think it is so simple.
You can just calculate 0xFFFFFF-YourColor. It will be the inverted color.

```
int neg = 0xFFFFFF - originalRGB

// optional: set alpha to 255:
int neg = (0xFFFFFF - originalRGB) | 0xFF000000;
```

Comment: Although this would invert Alpha as well... Might not what the OP wants... Try 0x00FFFFFF - YourColor instead

Comment: @CPUTerminator: That will not leave alpha unchanged either.  Something like `(0x00FFFFFFU - (input | 0xFF000000U)) | (input & 0xFF000000U)` should suffice.

Comment: @caf My mistake... Rushed through my comment... Could just do (0xFFFFFFFF - Color) + (0xFF000000 & Color) though.

Comment: @CPUTerminator: No, that would leave the alpha as 0xFF.

Comment: Yes this is the right one, although I ended up using bitwise XOR. Same result, same number of instructions (right?).

Comment: Mine was wrong too, it should actually be `(0x00FFFFFFU - (input & 0x00FFFFFFU)) | (input & 0xFF000000U)`

Comment: To make this a better answer, can you explain exactly what this code is doing to arrive at the result?

Answer (score 14):

Use this method to invert each color and maintain original alpha.

```
int invert(int color) {
  return color ^ 0x00ffffff;
}
```

xor (`^`) with 0 returns the original value unmodified.
xor with `0xff` flips the bits. so in the above case we have `0xaarrggbb` we are flipping/inverting r, g and b.

This should be the most efficient way to invert a color. arithmetic is (marginally) slower than this utterly simple bit-wise manipulation.

if you want to ignore original alpha, and just make it opaque, you can overwrite the alpha:

```
int invert(int color) {
  0xff000000 | ~color;
}
```

in this case we just flip every bit of color to inverse every channel including alpha, and then overwrite the alpha channel to opaque by forcing the first 8 bits high with `0xff000000`.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply perform the negation of the color. Snippet:

```
~ color
```

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution, I guess it would have the alpha inverting issue though

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear; no colors in RGB are "negative colors".

You could invert an image, as though it was a film negative.  Is that what you meant?

If you wanted to invert an image that has just one pixel of color `0xFF00FF`, the calculation is to subtract from white, `0xFFFFFF`.

```
> negative_result_color = 0xFFFFFF - 0xFF00FF
> negative_result_color == 0x00FF00
true
```

In a computer, a subtraction is done by *adding* the compliment:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements#Binary_example

But seriously, why wouldn't you just let the machine do the subtraction for you with your ordinary code?  Its what they're *good* at.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color color_original = Color.lightGray;

int rgb = color_original.getRGB();

int inverted = (0x00FFFFFF - (rgb | 0xFF000000)) | (rgb & 0xFF000000);

Color color_inverted = new Color(inverted);
```