# How can we invert hex-color code?

Tags: android, colors, hex

My Web API will send the background color for my views, Background color range is from white `#ffffff` to black `#000000`. So I can not set any fix text color for my information text.
What is the best way to set my text color?
I'm thinking to invert the background color and set it as my text color. But I don't know How can I invert Any color or Hex color code.

**e.g if my web(background) color is #00ff11 then my text color will be #ff00ee.**

For this, I search over stack but did not find any method for color conversion.

Thanks

Comment: programming basics: **binary/bitwise not** ... if you would know java's basics then you would know that there is operator for this

Comment: Actually, I'm IOS dev, Helping my friend to get text color from the background color.

Comment: Lol ... Swift has bitwise not operator too ... it's the same as in Java, C, C#, Objective-C, Python...

Comment: So, checking for bitmap and all. but don't know how to invert color or invert hex color code as max as 255

Comment: In swift/objective-C we can easily invert color, with some set of logic :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invert an RGB color in integer form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141976/how-to-invert-an-rgb-color-in-integer-form)

Comment: Maybe, this is a duplicate question. As I'm new to android syntax. But I write here as I did not find my logic here... Thanks for helping

Comment: **It is not platform/language dependent** [This should know every programmer  not mention about Sr. Software Engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

This will give rgb of your hex color. Now you can invert your colors as below.

```
int invertColor(String myColorString) {

    int color = (int)Long.parseLong(myColorString, 16);
    int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
    int invertedRed = 255 - r;
    int invertedGreen = 255 - g;
    int invertedBlue = 255 - b;

    int invertedColor = Color.rgb(invertedRed, invertedGreen, invertedBlue);

    return invertedColor.toString();
}
```

Comment: Let me check it, please give me few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
private PaintType getNegativePaintType(String hexa) {
    int color = Color.parseColor(hexa);
    return new SolidColor((color & 0xFF000000) | (~color & 0x00FFFFFF));
}
```

**getNegativePaintType("#00ff11")** will return **"#ff00ee"**

Comment: Please give me a moment, let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Independently of the platform your using, you can achieve that using RGB values simply by subtracting the used color from it's base (255).
So for example:

```
color = (r,g,b)
invertedColor = (255-r,255-g,255-b)
```

Then you could transform it to hexadecimal value or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/jnhmcknight/6e39dee9bd1c515825a4b1530bf5945f).

```
def invert_hex(content):
    text = content.group(1).lower()
    code = {}
    l1="0123456789abcdef"
    l2="fedcba9876543210"
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        code[l1[i]]=l2[i]
    inverted = ""
    for j in text:
        inverted += code[j]
    return '#{}'.format(inverted)


import re
re_hex = re.compile("#([0-9a-f]{3,6})(\W)?", re.IGNORECASE)
c = re_hex.sub(invert_hex, '#00ff11')
print(c) # >>> #ff00ee
```