# Javascript. Find the Inverse of a Hex code

Tags: javascript, html, hex, inverse

I was just working with HTML hex color codes and wondered if there is any easy way to calculate the inverse of any color code using plan javascript.

```
const hex = "#xxxxxx";
const inverseHex = "#yyyyyy";

const add = hex + inverseHex; // #000000
```

Comment: Er, do you really want `#000000`? If so, just reference `hex`? I don't get it

Comment: @juancho do mean that black would become white? `#000000` (black) to `#ffffff` (white). If so you answer is here to convert the hex into rgb and subtract each value from white. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969656/how-can-i-generate-the-opposite-color-according-to-current-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate the opposite color according to current color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969656/how-can-i-generate-the-opposite-color-according-to-current-color)

Answer (score 1):

My 50 cents:

```js
const inv = (hex) => '#' + hex.match(/[a-f0-9]{2}/ig).map(e => (255 - parseInt(e, 16) | 0).toString(16).replace(/^([a-f0-9])$/, '0$1')).join('')

const invert = () =>
  document.querySelectorAll('circle')
    .forEach(c => 
      (hex = c.getAttribute('fill')) && 
      c.setAttribute('fill', inv(hex))
    )

console.log('#000000', inv('#000000'))
console.log('#ffffff', inv('#ffffff'))
console.log('#ff6600', inv('#ff6600'))
console.log('#fe4289', inv('#fe4289'))
```

```css
body {
  background: grey
}

svg {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<svg><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#000000"/></svg>
<svg><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#ffffff"/></svg>
<svg><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#ff6600"/></svg>
<svg><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#fe4289"/></svg>

<p><button onclick="invert()">Invert!</button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function inverse(figure) {
  // inverse a RGB color
  return ((figure & 0x000000) | (~figure & 0xFFFFFF))
}

var a = document.querySelector('#a')

var b = document.querySelector('#b')

var color = "#FF00FF"

var inversedColor = "#" + inverse(parseInt(color.substr(1), 16))
  .toString(16)
  .padStart(6, "0")
  .toUpperCase();
a.style.background = color;

b.style.background = inversedColor;

console.log(color, inversedColor);
```

```html
<button id=a>Button A</button>

<button id=b>Button B</button>
```

credits for the inverse function : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387888/750852

Comment: Seems like `function inverse (figure) {return 0xFFFFFF - figure}` would be a little easier on the eyes. It's the same isn't it?

Comment: Use (0x00FFFFFF - (rgba | 0xFF000000)) | (rgba & 0xFF000000); if you don't want opaque white to become transparent black.

Comment: regarding `figure & 0x000000` `(anything & 0) === 0`